# What is the lightbulb icon in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom, on this particular line, a light bulb icon appears.  Left-clicking and right-clicking seem to emit the same behavior they would if I clicked in the same part of any other line.

What is it? Why is it there and is there something I can do about it?  It looks an awful lot like an icon I've seen in Visual Studio, which usually displayed some helpful tips to help me with my code.

[image: LightBulb icon in Atom]

Comment: Try launching the DevTools (with `CTRL/CMD + Shift + I`) and use inspect element to see what's its class - that'd help us find it :)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia great idea, the div that renders that line number has a 'quickfix' class that the others don't have. I think you've found the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It indicates that there is a TypeScript 'Quick Fix' available at that line. See the following documentation:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/quickfix.md

Press `ctrl+enter` to show the quick fixes.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that a "Quick Fix" is available.

You can press Alt+Enter at the location of error to view the options, then select the desired quick fix and hit enter.

[image: Image from atom-typescript github]